# C++ writing into .log file doesn't work in unit test project

Tags: c++, unit-testing, exception, logging

I am using Visual Studio, C++, sqlapi and the Microsoft Unit Testing Framework for C++.

I wrote a simple method in my main project for writing some errors into a .log file when an exception is coming. The method is calling when I am catching a SAException.

```
void LogException(const SAException& e)
    {
        auto now = system_clock::now();
        auto now_c = system_clock::to_time_t(now);

        stringstream ss;
        ss << put_time(localtime(&now_c), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") << "\n" << (const char*)e.ErrText() << "\n\n";
        ofstream logfile("exceptions.log", ios_base::app);cout << put_time(localtime(&now_c), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") << "\n" << (const char*)e.ErrText() << "\n\n";
        logfile << ss.str();
        logfile.close();
    }
```

As far as I am only running the project in Visual Studio everythings fine and the .log file got some text. Now I am using a second project with the the Microsoft Unit Testing Framework for C++ and do some unit testsing for my methods. When I now run my tests the .log file is not getting new entries but the tests themselves are working fine as always.

One test method where the .log file should get a new entry.

```
TEST_METHOD(openConnnectionException)
        {
            myDb->initParameter("dsn", "user", "pw", "client", "db");
            Assert::IsTrue(myDb->openConnection() == -1);
        }
```

the openConnection() method

```
int openConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            //trying to open the connection
        }
        catch (SAException& sae)
        {
            cout << "Error opening database. Check parameters or contact an administrator\n";
            LogException(sae);
            return -1;
        }
    };
```

My code is going trough the catch block and the LogException() method giving me the right return value but the .log file is still not getting a new entry. Somebody got any ideas why it's not working?

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case, I would guess your unit tests are run in a different path and that is why the file will exist in a different directory then when you run it in your IDE.

That said, your unit tests should not write files. You should have a different handler for exceptions for testing, one that you can *assert* on, so that your test can actually say "this *should* have produced a log entry". That means you need a way to write into one container *per test*. Probably an in-memory storage like a list/vector or other thing you can then query.